# Get images used in, but not attached to page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get all of the images used in a page. This is the code I'm using:

```
function get_page_images($id) {
    $photos = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => $id,
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

    $results = array();

    if ($photos) {
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            // get the correct image html for the selected size
            $results[] = wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, $size);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This only gets images uploaded specifically for this page, if I have reused an image that was already previously uploaded for a different page/post, those aren't retrieved (as they are attached to the post they were uploaded to, but not any posts they are reused in). Does anyone know a way to get **all** the images used in a page/post?

Comment: I *think* you would have to parse the HTML of the content to get *all* images. It would be relatively straightforward, though: 1. walk through the HTML and look for `img` tags 2. Find those with URLs pointing to your media folder 3. Grab them

Comment: That's what I thought, I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in PHP Dom Parser to grab all images located in your content. This code is untested, but should get you started in the right direction:

```
<?php
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(get_the_content());
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $img){
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        printf('<img src="%s" />', $src);
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: I was hoping for an obscure function/option that could do retrieve them but if that's not possible then this seems like the best course. I've adapted this for use outside the loop and it works great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think follwoing function will usefull for get images from post

```
function get_images_from_post( $id ) {
   $get_custom_post = get_post($id); 
   $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $get_custom_post->post_content, $matches);
   return $matches;
}
```